# alutCreateBufferHelloWorld () in openal

Tags: c++, openal

i need your help again in programing the openal

i am new in programing in general >>and start to learn openal by vc++ 6

and i am learning it from the doc that attachment with sdk1.1

and have this program

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <al.h>
#include <alc.h>
#include <alut.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "openal32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "alut.lib")


 ALCdevice *alcOpenDevice(ALCdevice *device);


 ALCenum alcGetError( ALCdevice *device );



 ALuint buffer ;
ALuint source;

// Position of the source sound.
ALfloat SourcePos[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

// Velocity of the source sound.
ALfloat SourceVel[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };


// Position of the Listener.
ALfloat ListenerPos[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

// Velocity of the Listener.
ALfloat ListenerVel[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

// Orientation of the Listener. (first 3 elements are "at", second 3 are "up")
// Also note that these should be units of '1'.
ALfloat ListenerOri[] = { 0.0, 0.0, -1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };



int  main()
{




alGenSources(1,&source);








 alSourcei (source, AL_BUFFER,  alutCreateBufferHelloWorld ());  

    alSourcef (source, AL_PITCH,    10.0      );
    alSourcef (source, AL_GAIN,     10.0      );
    //alSourcefv(source, AL_POSITION, SourcePos);
    //alSourcefv(source, AL_VELOCITY, SourceVel);
//  alSourcei (source, AL_LOOPING,  loop     );


alSourcePlay(source);


 alDeleteSources(1, &source);
return 0;

};
```

and i have an error

C:\Users\Toshiba\Desktop\Graduation Project\OpenAL\open AL test\EX\mi\ãËÇá\7\9\Cpp9.cpp(55) : error C2065: 'alutCreateBufferHelloWorld' : undeclared identifier
Error executing cl.exe.

and i dont konw what is the problem

thank alote

Comment: oooooooooooooh realy i need your help >>>and quikly

and i need your help about what i should do exactly to learn programing in openal during one month coz i need it n my graduation project and what is the best lang. to learn

Answer (score 1):

Either it's failing to find the alut.h header, in which case presumably you would get an error for that too, or your version of ALUT is too old and therefore does not have `alutCreateBufferHelloWorld` in the API.

Comment: thank you>>>>but how can i know the what is the version of my ALUT and what is the last version of ALUT and from where i can download it

Comment: @maiajam ALUT is a very old library, it is very unfindable, you may use OpenAL Soft, it is very simple. You need a WAVE reader, and a couple of calls you can find in ANY OpenAL tutorial.